# Trying To Make Cube In Java Without OpenGL

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, 3d, jframe

I'm quite new to Java programming but experienced in some other languages. I want to draw a cube in a JFrame window, found some code made by someone in lua, and struggled to convert it to java. This may be because I'm either not good enough at Java yet or because of the differences between the languages.

I have a main script that sets up the window and calls the cube script:

```js
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;
        String title = "Test";

        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        display.setTitle(title);
        display.setSize(width, height);
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        display.setContentPane(new Main());
    }

    public Main() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }
    
    

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Cube cube = new Cube();
        cube.paint(); // not sure how to call cube correctly!
    }
}
```

However I don't think it has called the cube script correctly!

Next I made the cube script that set up the cube, however there are multiple errors found next to the quotations.

```js
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.*;

public class Cube {

 public int focalLength = 300;
 
 int[] Make3dPoint(int x, int y, int z) {
  int[] point = new int[3];
  point[0]=x;
  point[1]=y;
  point[2]=z;
  return point;
 }
 
 int[] Make2dPoint(int x, int y) {
  int[] point = new int[2];
  point[0]=x+240;
  point[1]=y+131;
  return point;
 }
 
 List Trans3dTo2d(ArrayList points[], ArrayList axisRotations[]) { // both arrays aren't being used!
  List TransformedPoints = new ArrayList();
  
  int sx = Math.sin(axisRotations.x); // Not finding x or y or z in any of these??
  int cx = Math.coz(axisRotations.x);
  int sy = Math.sin(axisRotations.y);
  int cy = Math.coz(axisRotations.y);
  int sz = Math.sin(axisRotations.z);
  int cz = Math.coz(axisRotations.z);
  
  int x;int y;int z;
  int xy = x*y;int xz = x*z;int yx = y*x;int yz = y*z;int zx = z*x;int zy = z*y; // coupling the variables! not sure if this is correct
  
  int i = points.length;
  while(i>0) {
   x = points[i].x; // again can't find x, y or z??
   y = points[i].y;
   z = points[i].z;
   
   xy = cx*y - sx*z;
   xz = sx*y + cx*z;
   
   yz = cy*xz - sy*x;
   yx = sy*xz + cy*x;
   
   zx = cz*yx - sz*xy;
   zy = sz*yx + cz*xy;
   
   int scaleRatio = focalLength/(focalLength + yz);
   
   x = zx*scaleRatio;
   y = zy*scaleRatio;
   
   TransformedPoints = new Make2dPoint(x,y); // not set up correctly??
   i=i-1;
  }
  
  return TransformedPoints;
 }
 List pointsArray;{  // making points in 3d space! wanted ";" but not sure if correct
  Make3dPoint(-50, -50, -50);
     Make3dPoint(50, -50, -50);
     Make3dPoint(50, -50, 50);
     Make3dPoint(-50, -50, 50);
     Make3dPoint(-50, 50, -50);
     Make3dPoint(50, 50, -50);
     Make3dPoint(50, 50, 50);
     Make3dPoint(-50, 50, 50);
 }
 
 float UserX = (float) -0.01;
 float UserY = (float) 0.01;
 List cubeAxisRotation = make3dPoint(0,0,0);
 
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
  cubeAxisRotation.x = cubeAxisRotation.x + UserX; // again not recognising x or y value
  cubeAxisRotation.y = cubeAxisRotation.y + UserY;
  
  List sp = new Trans3dTo2d(pointsArray, cubeAxisRotation); // doesn't like this!
  
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawLine(sp[1].x, sp[1].y, sp[2].x, sp[2].y); // not recognising this in all lines! 
        g.drawLine(sp[2].x, sp[2].y, sp[3].x, sp[3].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[3].x, sp[3].y, sp[4].x, sp[4].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[4].x, sp[4].y, sp[1].x, sp[1].y);
        
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawLine(sp[5].x, sp[5].y, sp[6].x, sp[6].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[6].x, sp[6].y, sp[7].x, sp[7].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[7].x, sp[7].y, sp[8].x, sp[8].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[8].x, sp[8].y, sp[5].x, sp[5].y);
        
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(sp[1].x, sp[1].y, sp[5].x, sp[5].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[2].x, sp[2].y, sp[6].x, sp[6].y);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawLine(sp[3].x, sp[3].y, sp[7].x, sp[7].y);
        g.drawLine(sp[4].x, sp[4].y, sp[8].x, sp[8].y);
 }
}
```

I don't even know if the paint method will work. This has came from the link provided below. I didn't copy and paste as I printed it off and couldn't find it until now and has taken hours to make. It might give a better idea of how this works and if anyone wants to use it too.

https://gist.github.com/Ipad41001/1335691

I'm mostly stuck on working with the arrays and calling methods, simple things, but finding it hard at the same time.

Thank you for any help!

:)

Comment: `ArrayList points[]` is a **raw** type. None of your `List`(s) are typed. Also, making arrays of `List`s is probably not what you want, but this code is very difficult to read.

Comment: `List pointsArray;{` - no. That's a `null` pointsArray, and then an initialization block that you throw away.

Comment: Ok thanks but please put it in answers if you have any improvements please